# Looping through set stops after first run - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to this and so building a script to learn how to scrape.
I'm querying a main index page for a list of URLs that then contain the contact information I want.

I successfully get the index list into a set and then try to iterate through it by use of two functions (I'm sure there is a better way to do this). After the first iteration, it stops and I simply don't understand why. Any pointers appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

linkset = set()
url = "http://someurl.com/venues"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

base_url = "http://someurl.com/uk/"
links = soup.find_all("a", class_="supplier-link")


# A function to get the links from the top level directory.
def get_venue_link_list(links):
    for link in links:
        linkset.add(link.get("href"))
        return linkset

#get_venue_link_list(links)
# When I test by printing linkset, I get the list of unique URL's.
# This works as expected.
#print linkset

# A function to go retrieve contact

def go_retrieve_contact(link_value):
    for i in link_value:
        link = i
        venue_link = base_url + link
        venue_request = requests.get(venue_link)
        venue_soup = BeautifulSoup(venue_request.content, "lxml")
        info = venue_soup.find_all("section", {"class": "findout"})
        header = venue_soup.find_all("div", {"id": "supplier-header-desktop"})
        go_get_info(info)
# Email, Phone and Website was nested in one div so it was a little easier to get.
# Will need to use a different div for address and social media names.

def go_get_info(info):
    for item in info:
        print "%s" % ((item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[0].text)).strip()
        print "%s" % ((item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[1].text)).strip()
        print "%s" % ((item.contents[3].find_all("span", {"class": "text"})[2].text)).strip()
        #Lets comment out this next nested loop until I fix the above.
        #for item in header:
            #print item.contents[1].text

go_retrieve_contact(get_venue_link_list(links))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` causes the function to exit completely. The way you've written it, you've told the function to return immediately after the first iteration - so it's no wonder it stops then. :)

This is an indenting issue - what you really want is:

```
def get_venue_link_list(links):
    for link in links:
        linkset.add(link.get("href"))
    return linkset
```

This lets the loop finish first, and *then* exit.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't give it a change to continue the iteration.  You `return` inside the loop, so it doesn't get to the second iteration.  You need to un-indent that line:

```
def get_venue_link_list(links):
    for link in links:
        linkset.add(link.get("href"))
    return linkset
```

Answer (score 2):

In `get_venue_link_list()` you have a return statement within the loop.  This causes the function to exit the first time it is reached so you never make it beyond the first iteration.  Remove the indent from the last line of this function.